# PyCharm: Run pub build as an external tool

Tags: dart, pycharm, dart-pub

I am using PyCharm IDE with Dart plugin which allows running `pub get`, `pub build`, etc. easily by clicking a "link" when looking at the `.yaml` file. I'm using dart stuff inside my pyramid app and I would like to automatically build the dart stuff before every launch of the application.

Question: Is it possible to use the Dart plugin to do the `pub` stuff using the external tools feature of PyCharm?

I could still define the external tool explicitly by calling the `pub` program in the right working directory, but this does not allow me to use one dart sdk setting for this external tool and for the dart support for my app.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, configuring 'pub build' as an External Tool and adding it to the 'before launch' section of the Run Configuration is the correct way.
Unfortunately if you change Dart SDK folder you have to update path in 2 places: in Preferences (Settings) | Dart page and in the External Tool configuration.

I have filed a feature request to add native support for 'Run Pub Build before launch', feel free to vote and comment: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-13893